# Apple Event object property hasAlarms returning incorrect boolean value

Tags: ffi, livecode, eventkit

I am attempting to wrap a number of EkEventkit objective-c commands using Livecode Builder using its Foreign Function Interface (FFI).  I have created a library for use by Livecode Script but when run the Event property "hasAlarms" returns true on events that have no alarm set.  The odd thing is that repeat events that were entered into my calendar many years ago and therefore several OS versions ago appear to report correct values.

The FFI definition I am using is

```
private foreign handler Objc_EventHasAlarms(in pEventObj as objcID) \
                        returns optional CBool \
                        binds to "objc:EventKit>EKEvent.hasAlarms"
```

The code above does not throw any errors so I wonder if I have stumbled across a bug in the Calendar (v11) application running on Big Sur.  Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is likely caused by your return value `returns optional CBool` which should be `returns CBool`

So:

```
private foreign handler Objc_EventHasAlarms(in pEventObj as ObjcId) \
                        returns CBool \
                        binds to "objc:EventKit>EKCalendarItem.-hasAlarms"
```

A further suggestion would be to check the result of:

```
private foreign handler Objc_EventAlarms(in pEventObj as ObjcId) \
                        returns optional ObjcId \
                        binds to "objc:EventKit>EKCalendarItem.-alarms"
```

via:

```
if Objc_EventAlarms(tCalendarItem) is nothing then
   -- no alarms
end if
```

Comment: I made the changes you suggest but hasAlarms still returns true when no alarm is set.  However, I managed to add an event from an old computer running iCal.   This test event appeared in my Big Sur computer and was assigned an alarm by default.  I removed the alarm and false was correctly returned.  So I suspect issue is with Eventkit.  I added the "-" which suggests there is a Getter method despite none mentioned in Apple documents - is this the case?